# I create object of class and get an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Tags: kotlin, stack-overflow

I create class Person. Now I try create list with an object of this class. And when I create it I get this error:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at BodyKt$main$Person.(body.kt:9)". What I did wrong?

```
fun main() {
    // copy object in object
    class Person (var name: String = "Orig", var type: String = "piece",
                       var age: Int = 18, var high: Double = 25.7, var code: Int = 1522)
    {
        var info: String = "0"
            get() = "Name: $name Age: $age Type: $type High: $high Code: $code"
        var somebody : List<Person> = listOf(
            Person("Copy", "some", 15, 11.1, 1870))
    }
    var default: Person = Person()
    val ann: Person = Person("Ann", "man", 10, 0.5, 1408) // 1st object with some properties
    var bob: Person = Person("Bob", "girl", 20, 15.0, 1239) // 2nd object without prop
    println("Properties of Ann: ${ann.info}") // props 1st object
    println("Properties of Bob: ${bob.info}") // props 2nd object
    println("Default: ${default.info}") // props default
    bob = ann.deepCopy() // copy 1st in 2nd
    println("Bob has Anns' props: ${bob.info}") // new props 2nd object
    println("Default list: ${default.somebody}")
}
```

Comment: It's because you create a Person instance, which then creates another Person instance, which then creates another... and so on. Eventually what you get is stack overflow.

The root of your problem is the `somebody` property. Try using `get()` notation for it in order to create it lazily / on-demand, and that should address your issue. More here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: But I read: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/list-operations.html and there write
 
`val productList = listOf(
    Product("WebStorm", 49.0),
    Product("AppCode", 99.0),
    Product("DotTrace", 129.0),
    Product("ReSharper", 149.0))

println(productList.binarySearch(Product("AppCode", 99.0), compareBy<Product> { it.price }.thenBy { it.name }))` What have I understood wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are instantiating a new `Person` every time a new instance of `Person` is created. That is causing infinite calls to `Person()`.

In Java, this would be like

```
class Person() {
    new Person()
}
```

Can you see the problem there?

While you are not doing it in the constructor, you are doing it on a field that is initialized when a new instance is created.

You can fix the exception by changing the field to be a getter. The `Person` list will not be created until someone actually tries to get it, removing the infinite loop.

```
val somebody
    get() = listOf(Person("Copy", "some", 15, 11.1, 1870))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but `var somebody` need to be initialized or you just skipped it? And last question: I read here: kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/list-operations.html and there are no any errors with create objects. `val productList = listOf( Product("WebStorm", 49.0), Product("AppCode", 99.0), Product("DotTrace", 129.0), Product("ReSharper", 149.0)) println(productList.binarySearch(Product("AppCode", 99.0), compareBy<Product> { it.price }.thenBy { it.name }))` What do I do wrong?

Comment: In that example they are not initializing the list inside the `Product` class when the class is being initialized. The problem with my example was I called it a `var` which has to be initialized to you could set it to `emptyList()` for example.